# Precision of repr(f), str(f), print(f) when f is float

Tags: python, floating-point-precision

If I run:

```
>>> import math
>>> print(math.pi)
3.141592653589793
```

Then pi is printed with 16 digits,

However, according to:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info.dig 
15
```

My precision is 15 digits.

So, should I rely on the last digit of that value (i.e. that the value of π indeed is 3.141592653589793nnnnnn).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The last digit of `str(float)` or `repr(float)` can be "wrong" in that it seems that the decimal representation is not correctly rounded.

```
>>> 0.100000000000000040123456
0.10000000000000003
```

But that value is still closer to the original than `0.1000000000000000` (with 1 digit less) is.

In the case of `math.pi`, the decimal approximation of pi is 3.14159265358979*3238463*..., in *this* case the last digit is right.

The `sys.float_info.dig` tells how many decimal digits are guaranteed to be *always* precise.

---

The default output for both `str(float)` and `repr(float)` in Python 3.1+ (and 2.7 for `repr`) is the shortest string that when converted to `float` will return the original value; in case of ambiguity, the last digit is rounded to the closest value. A float provides ~15.9 decimal digits of precision; but actually up to 17 decimal digit precision is required to represent a 53 binary digits unambiguously,

For example `0.10000000000000004` is between `0x1.999999999999dp-4` and `0x1.999999999999cp-4`, but the latter is closer; these 2 have the decimal expansions

```
0.10000000000000004718447854656915296800434589385986328125
```

and

```
0.100000000000000033306690738754696212708950042724609375
```

respectively. Clearly the latter is closer, so that binary representation is chosen.

Now when these are converted back to string with `str()`, or `repr()`, the shortest string that yields the exactly same value is chosen; for these 2 values they are `0.10000000000000005` and `0.10000000000000003` respectively

---

The precision of a `double` in IEEE-754 is 53 binary digits; in decimal you can calculate the precision by taking 10-based logarithm of 2^53,

```
>>> math.log(2 ** 53, 10)
15.954589770191001
```

meaning *almost* 16 digits of precision. The `float_info` precision tells how much you can always expect to be presentable, and this number is 15, for there are some numbers with 16 decimal digits that are indistinguishable.

---

However this is not the whole story. Internally what happens in Python 3.2+ is that the `float.__str__` and `float.__repr__` end up calling the same C method [`float_repr`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/430a2b541709/Objects/floatobject.c#l269):

```
float_repr(PyFloatObject *v)
{
    PyObject *result;
    char *buf;

    buf = PyOS_double_to_string(PyFloat_AS_DOUBLE(v),
                                'r', 0,
                                Py_DTSF_ADD_DOT_0,
                                NULL);
    if (!buf)
        return PyErr_NoMemory();
    result = _PyUnicode_FromASCII(buf, strlen(buf));
    PyMem_Free(buf);
    return result;
}
```

The `PyOS_double_to_string` then, for the `'r'` mode (standing for repr), calls either the `_Py_dg_dtoa` with mode 0, which is an internal routine to convert the double to a string, or `snprintf` with `%17g` for those platforms for which the `_Py_dg_dtoa` wouldn't work.

The behaviour snprintf is entirely platform dependent, but if `_Py_dg_dtoa` is used (as far as I understand, it should be used on most machines), it should be predictable.

The [`_Py_dg_dtoa` mode 0](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/430a2b541709/Python/dtoa.c#l2395) is specified as follows:

> 0 ==> shortest string that yields d when read in and rounded to nearest.

So, that is what happens - the yielded string must exactly reproduce the `double` value when read in, and it must be the shortest representation possible, and among multiple decimal representations that would be read in, it would be the one that is closest to the binary value. Now, this might also mean that the last digit of decimal expansion does *not* match the original value rounded at that length, only that the decimal representation is as close to the original binary representation as possible. Thus YMMV.