# Convert float to string in positional format (without scientific notation and false precision)

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, number-formatting, python-2.x

I want to print some floating point numbers so that they're always written in decimal form (e.g. `12345000000000000000000.0` or `0.000000000000012345`, not in [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), yet I'd want to the result to have the up to ~15.7 [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) of a IEEE 754 double, and no more.

What I want is ***ideally* so that the result is the *shortest* string in positional decimal format that still results in the same value when converted to a `float`**.

It is well-known that the `repr` of a `float` is written in scientific notation if the exponent is greater than 15, or less than -4:

```
>>> n = 0.000000054321654321
>>> n
5.4321654321e-08  # scientific notation
```

If `str` is used, the resulting string again is in scientific notation:

```
>>> str(n)
'5.4321654321e-08'
```

---

It has been suggested that I can use `format` with `f` flag and sufficient precision to get rid of the scientific notation:

```
>>> format(0.00000005, '.20f')
'0.00000005000000000000'
```

It works for that number, though it has some extra trailing zeroes. But then the same format fails for `.1`, which gives decimal digits beyond the actual machine precision of float:

```
>>> format(0.1, '.20f')
'0.10000000000000000555'
```

And if my number is `4.5678e-20`, using `.20f` would still lose relative precision:

```
>>> format(4.5678e-20, '.20f')
'0.00000000000000000005'
```

Thus **these approaches do not match my requirements**.

---

This leads to the question: what is the easiest and also well-performing way to print arbitrary floating point number in decimal format, having the same digits as in [`repr(n)` (or `str(n)` on Python 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28493269/918959), but always using the decimal format, not the scientific notation.

That is, a function or operation that for example converts the float value `0.00000005` to string `'0.00000005'`; `0.1` to `'0.1'`; `420000000000000000.0` to `'420000000000000000.0'` or `420000000000000000` and formats the float value `-4.5678e-5` as `'-0.000045678'`.

---

After the bounty period: It seems that there are at least 2 viable approaches, as Karin demonstrated that using string manipulation one can achieve significant speed boost compared to my initial algorithm on Python 2.

Thus,

- If performance is important and Python 2 compatibility is required; or if the `decimal` module cannot be used for some reason, then [Karin's approach using string manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38983595/918959) is the way to do it.
- On Python 3, [my somewhat shorter code will also be faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38847691/918959).

Since I am primarily developing on Python 3, I will accept my own answer, and shall award Karin the bounty.

Comment: And please if you do have a better answer to this question, do share it.

Comment: Project for a rainy day: add a low-level library function to Python (possibly in the `sys` module) that returns the "raw" binary-to-decimal conversion result for a given finite float (i.e., string of digits, decimal exponent, sign). That would give people the freedom to format as they saw fit.

Comment: Short answer: no, there isn't an easier way to do this; at least, not one that I'm aware of, and that also gives decently precise results. (Any solution that involves first pre-processing the number by scaling by powers of 10 is going to risk introducing numerical errors.)

Comment: since you required precision is 15.7 decimal digits ~= 16 decimal digits of precision why your examples request precision 20?

Comment: The 20 isn't precision but scale!

Comment: you wrote  `yet I'd want to keep the 15.7 decimal digits of precision and no more.` , also there is no such term like `scale`  when you speak about format function even you may refer to the same thing: The precision is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value

Comment: @AnttiHaapala in all your example the precision should be 16 not 20, also please remove 4.5678e-20 from your examples since your requested precision is bellow 16

Comment: @rusu_ro1 There are 2 different formats at play here: the source, which is floating point, and the destination fixed point representation. To me it seems that OP is interested in preserving the **source** format's precision to the given spec.

Comment: thx @IljaEverilä, this means that the OP post is incomplete?

Comment: I don't see it that way, it just takes a bit of reading.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that not even the new-style formatting with `float.__format__` supports this. The default formatting of `float`s is the same as with `repr`; and with `f` flag there are 6 fractional digits by default:

```
>>> format(0.0000000005, 'f')
'0.000000'
```

---

However there is a hack to get the desired result - not the fastest one, but relatively simple:

- first the float is converted to a string using `str()` or `repr()`
- then a new [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) instance is created from that string.
- `Decimal.__format__` supports `f` flag which gives the desired result, and, unlike `float`s it prints the actual precision instead of default precision.

Thus we can make a simple utility function `float_to_str`:

```
import decimal

# create a new context for this task
ctx = decimal.Context()

# 20 digits should be enough for everyone :D
ctx.prec = 20

def float_to_str(f):
    """
    Convert the given float to a string,
    without resorting to scientific notation
    """
    d1 = ctx.create_decimal(repr(f))
    return format(d1, 'f')
```

Care must be taken to not use the global decimal context, so a new context is constructed for this function. This is the fastest way; another way would be to use `decimal.local_context` but it would be slower, creating a new thread-local context and a context manager for each conversion.

This function now returns the string with all possible digits from mantissa, rounded to the [shortest equivalent representation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28493269/918959):

```
>>> float_to_str(0.1)
'0.1'
>>> float_to_str(0.00000005)
'0.00000005'
>>> float_to_str(420000000000000000.0)
'420000000000000000'
>>> float_to_str(0.000000000123123123123123123123)
'0.00000000012312312312312313'
```

The last result is rounded at the last digit

As @Karin noted, `float_to_str(420000000000000000.0)` does not strictly match the format expected; it returns `420000000000000000` without trailing `.0`.

Comment: Why don't you use [`decimal.localcontext`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html#decimal.localcontext)? `with localcontext() as ctx: ctx.prec = 20; d1 = Decimal(str(f))`

Comment: @Bakuriu why would I, it can only be slower

Comment: I see precision loss in the output for 0.000000000123123123123123123123 - the `float_to_str` output cuts off at only 12 digits of precision, not enough to reconstruct the original float.

Comment: @user2357112 good catch. You're using Python 2; in Python 2 `str` only has 12 digits of precision while `repr` uses the Python 3 compatible algorithm. In Python 3, both forms are similar, thus the confusion. I changed my code to use `repr`.

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thanks for the clear explanation

Comment: Why can't the global decimal context be used here?

Comment: @N4v who knows what the setting is :D

Answer (score 37):

If you are satisfied with the precision in scientific notation, then could we just take a simple string manipulation approach? Maybe it's not terribly clever, but it seems to work (passes all of the use cases you've presented), and I think it's fairly understandable:

```
def float_to_str(f):
    float_string = repr(f)
    if 'e' in float_string:  # detect scientific notation
        digits, exp = float_string.split('e')
        digits = digits.replace('.', '').replace('-', '')
        exp = int(exp)
        zero_padding = '0' * (abs(int(exp)) - 1)  # minus 1 for decimal point in the sci notation
        sign = '-' if f < 0 else ''
        if exp > 0:
            float_string = '{}{}{}.0'.format(sign, digits, zero_padding)
        else:
            float_string = '{}0.{}{}'.format(sign, zero_padding, digits)
    return float_string

n = 0.000000054321654321
assert(float_to_str(n) == '0.000000054321654321')

n = 0.00000005
assert(float_to_str(n) == '0.00000005')

n = 420000000000000000.0
assert(float_to_str(n) == '420000000000000000.0')

n = 4.5678e-5
assert(float_to_str(n) == '0.000045678')

n = 1.1
assert(float_to_str(n) == '1.1')

n = -4.5678e-5
assert(float_to_str(n) == '-0.000045678')
```

**Performance**:

I was worried this approach may be too slow, so I ran `timeit` and compared with the OP's solution of decimal contexts. It appears the string manipulation is actually quite a bit faster. **Edit**: It appears to only be much faster in Python 2. In Python 3, the results were similar, but with the decimal approach slightly faster.

**Result**:

- Python 2: using `ctx.create_decimal()`: `2.43655490875`
- Python 2: using string manipulation: `0.305557966232`
- Python 3: using `ctx.create_decimal()`: `0.19519368198234588`
- Python 3: using string manipulation: `0.2661344590014778`

Here is the timing code:

```
from timeit import timeit

CODE_TO_TIME = '''
float_to_str(0.000000054321654321)
float_to_str(0.00000005)
float_to_str(420000000000000000.0)
float_to_str(4.5678e-5)
float_to_str(1.1)
float_to_str(-0.000045678)
'''
SETUP_1 = '''
import decimal

# create a new context for this task
ctx = decimal.Context()

# 20 digits should be enough for everyone :D
ctx.prec = 20

def float_to_str(f):
    """
    Convert the given float to a string,
    without resorting to scientific notation
    """
    d1 = ctx.create_decimal(repr(f))
    return format(d1, 'f')
'''
SETUP_2 = '''
def float_to_str(f):
    float_string = repr(f)
    if 'e' in float_string:  # detect scientific notation
        digits, exp = float_string.split('e')
        digits = digits.replace('.', '').replace('-', '')
        exp = int(exp)
        zero_padding = '0' * (abs(int(exp)) - 1)  # minus 1 for decimal point in the sci notation
        sign = '-' if f < 0 else ''
        if exp > 0:
            float_string = '{}{}{}.0'.format(sign, digits, zero_padding)
        else:
            float_string = '{}0.{}{}'.format(sign, zero_padding, digits)
    return float_string
'''

print(timeit(CODE_TO_TIME, setup=SETUP_1, number=10000))
print(timeit(CODE_TO_TIME, setup=SETUP_2, number=10000))
```

Comment: You could actually specify the initialization (`def format_float`; `import decimal; ctx = ...`) as the second argument to `timeit`; that way it doesn't get included to the measurements.

Comment: Ahh that seems obvious from the docs now. Great to know! I've updated my timing code and it looks much cleaner now thanks to you :)

Comment: I need to add one more case to test, though. The number can be negative, your's still calculates `n = -4.5678e-5`; `assert(format_float(n) == '-0.000045678')` incorrectly :D

Comment: And another gotcha more: This is way faster on Python 2 than my code, but slower on Python 3; seems that in Python 3 the decimal constructor performs much better than in Python 2.

Comment: I'm consistently surprised how often the naive "just stringify it" approach works, and sometimes works even better than other cases.

Comment: @Antti Fascinating! I can confirm your approach is must faster in Python 3 than Python 2. Another weirdness though, is that the `420000000000000000.0` use case actually fails for me for your decimal approach in Python 2 and 3. Very strange =\

Comment: @Karin it is because it seems that if `decimal` has more than 16 places, there is no `.0` any longer.

Comment: @Antti But then how did it work for you in your answer's example usage?

Comment: Frankly, I didn't remember that the returned string was without `.0`, I didn't copy-paste my example output from Python shell, instead writing it here. Good catch :D I fixed my answer.

Comment: `decimal` has received [several speed improvements in Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#decimal) (switch to libmpdec, caching, etc.) leading to 10x - 100x performance gains depending on what you are trying to make it do.

Comment: Karin, not only were you the only answerer to understand what I sought for, but you also found a clever approach to achieve it using string manipulation that performs very well on Python 2. :D Thus I awarded the bounty to you.

However, I chose to accept my self-answer in this case since the project for which we needed this uses Python 3, and we're already successfully using my approach.

Comment: (Ah one more thing, this should be using `repr` instead of `str` to [get consistent results Python 2 vs 3.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847690/convert-float-to-string-without-scientific-notation-and-false-precision/38847691?noredirect=1#comment65401025_38847691))

Comment: @Antti Thanks! This was a fun use case :) Also updated my code to use `repr` as suggested.

Comment: Good answer, but to be honest, I feel like this should be implemented in python directly and doable through `.format`. I don't see why `.format` doesn't include this use case. Printing a number in non-scientific notation with significant figures for example requires a hack like this. Yet I imagine it's an extremely common use case for plotting scientific figures with short logarithmic scales.

Comment: still not working for `float_to_str(333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333)`

Comment: this only works when exp in float_to_str() is <0. The 3rd test case happens to work because there is only one decimal digit in the scientific notation. It won't work if there are more than 1.  (n = 421000000000000000.0 will not work)

Comment: why there is wrong result ： float_to_str(27052805291130213231.64)
Out[440]: '27052805291130212000000000000000000.0'

Answer (score 31):

As of NumPy 1.14.0, you can just use [`numpy.format_float_positional`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_positional.html). For example, running against the inputs from your question:

```
>>> numpy.format_float_positional(0.000000054321654321)
'0.000000054321654321'
>>> numpy.format_float_positional(0.00000005)
'0.00000005'
>>> numpy.format_float_positional(0.1)
'0.1'
>>> numpy.format_float_positional(4.5678e-20)
'0.000000000000000000045678'
```

`numpy.format_float_positional` uses the Dragon4 algorithm to produce the shortest decimal representation in positional format that round-trips back to the original float input. There's also `numpy.format_float_scientific` for scientific notation, and both functions offer optional arguments to customize things like rounding and trimming of zeros.

Comment: Hey, that's nice. Not practical if NumPy is not needed otherwise, but if it is this is definitely what one should be using.

Comment: Even better answer. Though my opinion is that this functionality should be included directly as an option in the `.format` method for strings. Decimal representations with a significant figure limit are an extremely common use case in scientific graphs with logarithmic scales.

Comment: numpy.format_float_positional(27052805291130213231.64)=='27052805291130212000.'

Comment: @CSQGB: That's normal. Floats don't have enough precision to represent all the digits of 27052805291130213231.64. The value gets rounded to a float with exact numeric value 27052805291130212352, and `'27052805291130212000.'` is the shortest (in terms of minimum significant digits) decimal representation in positional format that produces that same float.

Comment: Note that the question specifically wanted to avoid reporting false precision, and asked for "the result to have the up to ~15.7 significant figures of a IEEE 754 double, and no more". Returning `'27052805291130212352.'` would go against what the question asked for (and the float doesn't contain enough information to return `'27052805291130213231.64'`).

Answer (score 6):

If you are ready to lose your precision arbitrary by calling `str()` on the float number, then it's the way to go:

```
import decimal

def float_to_string(number, precision=20):
    return '{0:.{prec}f}'.format(
        decimal.Context(prec=100).create_decimal(str(number)),
        prec=precision,
    ).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') or '0'
```

It doesn't include global variables and allows you to choose the precision yourself. Decimal precision 100 is chosen as an upper bound for `str(float)` length. The actual supremum is much lower. The `or '0'` part is for the situation with small numbers and zero precision.

Note that it still has its consequences:

```
>> float_to_string(0.10101010101010101010101010101)
'0.10101010101'
```

Otherwise, if the precision is important, `format` is just fine:

```
import decimal

def float_to_string(number, precision=20):
    return '{0:.{prec}f}'.format(
        number, prec=precision,
    ).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') or '0'
```

It doesn't miss the precision being lost while calling `str(f)`.
The `or`

```
>> float_to_string(0.1, precision=10)
'0.1'
>> float_to_string(0.1)
'0.10000000000000000555'
>>float_to_string(0.1, precision=40)
'0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021182'

>>float_to_string(4.5678e-5)
'0.000045678'

>>float_to_string(4.5678e-5, precision=1)
'0'
```

Anyway, maximum decimal places are limited, since the `float` type itself has its limits and cannot express really long floats:

```
>> float_to_string(0.1, precision=10000)
'0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625'
```

Also, whole numbers are being formatted as-is.

```
>> float_to_string(100)
'100'
```

Comment: There is no need to create that Decimal at all, your approach works for `float`s already, but the result of false precision was rejected in the question. These are rounded measurement results, not some arbitrary binary fractions.

Answer (score 3):

I think `rstrip` can get the job done.

```
a=5.4321654321e-08
'{0:.40f}'.format(a).rstrip("0") # float number and delete the zeros on the right
# '0.0000000543216543210000004442039220863003' # there's roundoff error though
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately as I stated in my question, I do not want any residual fractional part from the fact that these happened to be stored as binary.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, to add a little bit more of content to the question, here's a litte test comparing @Antti Haapala and @Harold solutions outputs:

```
import decimal
import math

ctx = decimal.Context()


def f1(number, prec=20):
    ctx.prec = prec
    return format(ctx.create_decimal(str(number)), 'f')


def f2(number, prec=20):
    return '{0:.{prec}f}'.format(
        number, prec=prec,
    ).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')

k = 2*8

for i in range(-2**8,2**8):
    if i<0:
        value = -k*math.sqrt(math.sqrt(-i))
    else:
        value = k*math.sqrt(math.sqrt(i))

    value_s = '{0:.{prec}E}'.format(value, prec=10)

    n = 10

    print ' | '.join([str(value), value_s])
    for f in [f1, f2]:
        test = [f(value, prec=p) for p in range(n)]
        print '\t{0}'.format(test)
```

Neither of them gives "consistent" results for all cases.

- With Anti's you'll see strings like '-000' or '000'
- With Harolds's you'll see strings like ''

I'd prefer consistency even if I'm sacrificing a little bit of speed. Depends which tradeoffs you want to assume for your use-case.

Comment: Why are you adjusting the precision in my approach? I fixed it to 20 to get all of the 15.7 decimal digits of precision of IEEE-754 doubles.

Answer (score 0):

using format(float, ' .f '):

```
old = 0.00000000000000000000123
if str(old).__contains__('e-'):
    float_length = str(old)[-2:]
    new=format(old,'.'+str(float_length)+'f')
    print(old)
    print(new)
```