# Python split function shows some wrong result

Tags: python

currently I am developing a program which helps user to adjust the significant figures. Hereby, I used following codes to split decimal numbers by [integer, ., decimal] format using split('.')

```
len_number1 = (str(number1)).split('.')
```

when I enter the value of 1.3333 it successfully separate numbers into ['1', '.', '3333'] but when I enter the value of 0.000043 it shows the result of ['4', '3e-05'] whereby I need to get the result of ['0', '.', '000043']

Is there any ways to solve such problem?

Comment: What's the `number1`?if `number1` is `1.3333`,it will be `['1', '3333']
` instead of `['1', '.', '3333']` when you use `.split(".")`

Comment: My mistake, Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you do `str(0.43).split('.')` you will get `['0','43']` not `['0','.', '43']`. The problem is the casting function `str()`, because the string format of these decimal numbers, as @MarkMeyer said, is in a scientific notation, that means `str(0.000043)` will return you `'4.3e-05'`.
Even `print(0.000043)` will give you something like `4.3e-05` too. You can try something like this to replace that function:

```
import decimal

dec = decimal.Context()

dec.prec = 20  #this gives us a precition of 20 decimals

def num_to_str(n):

    dec1 = dec.create_decimal(repr(n))  
    return format(dec1, 'n')

print(num_to_str(0.0000043).split('.'))
>>>['0','0000043']
```

If you want to get `['0','.', '0000043']`, you could use `insert()`, since you will only add one `'.'` at index 1. You could try

```
num = num_to_str(0.0000043).split('.')
num.insert(1,'.')
print(num)
>>>['0','.', '0000043']
```

Checkout the documentation of [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html), [`repr()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/repr) and [`split()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) for more info.

Comment: is it impossible to make 0.000043 into ['4', '000043'] using split?

Comment: The problem isn't `split()` @JungJaeWon. It's that you need to turn the number into a string before calling split and `str(0.000043)` is `'4.3e-05'`

Comment: Yeah that´s right. So here is a trick to do this `str()` casting function for get the result you are looking for.

Comment: I thought making number1 as str(number1) will make number1 into string format. it isn't work in such way is it?

Comment: @JungJaeWon see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847690/convert-float-to-string-in-positional-format-without-scientific-notation-and-fa).

Comment: Yeah that's right, `str(n)` will convert `n` into a string. The thing is that the string format of these decimal numbers, as @MarkMeyer said, is in a scientific notation, that means `str(0.000043)` will return you `'4.3e-05'`. You can check this and another different  string casting functions in these [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847690/convert-float-to-string-in-positional-format-without-scientific-notation-and-fa).