# How to calculate decimals with 8 places?

Tags: python

I have this number:

```
value='0.00000036'
```

as string
I want to calculate how much is value*2 or value+value (`0.00000072`) and apparently it is not an easy task.
I tried to use :

```
decimal.Decimal(value)
```

and it gets me with :

```
Decimal('3.6E-7')
```

Everything works fine when i'm using higher number (`0.0000036`) but it's useless to me.

Comment: Okay, and what's wrong with the `Decimal('3.6E-7')` result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert float to string in positional format (without scientific notation and false precision)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847690/convert-float-to-string-in-positional-format-without-scientific-notation-and-fa)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I want to see : 0.00000072

Comment: @fdermishin It doesn't. I already have a string, I want to convert it to number, multiply, add and subtract and then display it.

Comment: So what is the problem? 3.6E-7 is the same as 0.00000036. Everything works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
value='0.00000036'
decimal_value = decimal.Decimal(value)
print(format(decimal_value, 'f'))
```

```
0.00000036
```

---

If you want to multiply it by 2, just do it like so:

```
value='0.00000036'
decimal_value = decimal.Decimal(value) * 2
print(format(decimal_value, 'f'))
```

```
0.00000072
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question of how to display the calculated of value+value. or value * 2. the excepted result should be 0.00000072

Comment: Did you try multiplying it by 2 then? Like `format(decimal_value * 2, 'f')`

Comment: format(decimal_value * 2, 'f')  gives me : ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

Comment: You need to multiply by 2 variable of type Decimal, but not of type str

Answer (score 0):

Just do this it will solve you problem of suppressing scientific notation.

```
import numpy as np
import decimal
value='0.00000036'
np.format_float_positional(decimal.Decimal(value), trim='-')
```

**Output:'0.00000036'**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `f` strings.

```
import decimal
value='0.00000036'
decimal_value = decimal.Decimal(value) * 2 # change * to + - / etc..
print(f'{decimal_value:f}') # means convert to float
```

Output:

```
0.00000072
```