# Prettier floats using yaml

Tags: python, yaml, double, precision

Whenever I use yaml dump to dump floats, they start to look ugly.

Input:

**a.yaml**

```
a: 0.000000015
```

When I read it in and then dump it to file again, it will look like:

**dumped.yaml**

```
a: 1.5e-08
```

Note that there's no fixed size I can go for, i.e. maybe someone wants to put a lot of zeros (and I am not "afraid" of e.g. a small fraction with 20 leading zeros)

Also, if you choose a fixed size, then it might look like the following (which I am trying to avoid as well)

```
a: 0.0000000150000
```

Comment: Can you clarify which library you're using? PyYAML, ruamel.yamel or something else?

Comment: @SuperStormer I am using PyYAML, thanks for asking.

Comment: what is your way of choosing a fixed size?

Comment: @WalterTross I am not choosing a fixed size currently, might be the solution actually...

Comment: Not easy though:
`"{:.30f}".format(0.01)` yields
`'0.010000000000000000208166817117'`

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been able to find, in the [format specification mini-language documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec), a way to format numbers the way you want them.

I propose a simple hack: to replace, in the output of PyYAML, all numbers in scientific notation with their fixed-point equivalent, like this:

```python
import re
import yaml

# only accepts Python's/PyYAML's default scientific format, on purpose:
E_REGEX = re.compile(r'(\b|-)([1-9])(?:\.(\d+))?e([+-])(\d+)\b')

def e_to_f(match):
    sf, f0, f1, se, e = match.groups()
    if f1 is None: f1 = ''
    f = f0 + f1
    n = int(e)
    if se == '-':
        z = n - 1  # i.e., n - len(f0)
        if z < 0:
            return sf + f[:-z] + '.' + f[-z:]
        else:
            return sf + '0.' + '0' * z + f
    else:
        z = n - len(f1)
        if z < 0:
            return sf + f[:z] + '.' + f[z:]
        else:
            return sf + f + '0' * z + '.0'

e_dict = {
    'example': 1.5e-15,
    'another': -3.14e+16
}
e_txt = yaml.dump(e_dict, sort_keys=False)
f_txt = E_REGEX.sub(e_to_f, e_txt)
print(e_txt)
print(f_txt)

# output:
#
# example: 1.5e-15
# another: -3.14e+16
#
# example: 0.0000000000000015
# another: -31400000000000000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass `yaml.Dumper` to override the representer method for floats with one that only outputs standard notation. This method should be less hacky than regex substitution.

```
import decimal

import yaml

# from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38847691/7941251
ctx = decimal.Context()
ctx.prec = 20  # change for more precision

def float_to_str(f):
    """
    Convert the given float to a string,
    without resorting to scientific notation
    """
    d1 = ctx.create_decimal(repr(f))
    return format(d1, 'f')

class CustomDumper(yaml.SafeDumper):
    # modified from https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/master/lib3/yaml/representer.py#L171
    def represent_float(self, data):
        if data != data or (data == 0.0 and data == 1.0):
            value = '.nan'
        elif data == self.inf_value:
            value = '.inf'
        elif data == -self.inf_value:
            value = '-.inf'
        else:
            value = float_to_str(data).lower()
        return self.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:float', value)

CustomDumper.add_representer(float, CustomDumper.represent_float)

print(yaml.dump({"a": 0.000000015}, Dumper=CustomDumper)) # a: 0.000000015
```

Feel free to change `float_to_str` to a different method for converting floats to standard notation.

Comment: I suggest to give a different name to the `Dumper` class, in order to avoid confusion with `yaml.Dumper`