# What is the meaning of float(sys.maxsize)?

Tags: python, sys

[image]

I’m studying about sys.maxsize .

As I know, sys.maxsize means largest “integer” value that py_ssize_t can store.

and I compared
**float(sys.maxsize)**
and
**sys.maxsize**.

And I found there is difference between them which is **point(.)**

Even though I put sys.maxsize into float,

> Doesn’t it has to be bigger than 9.22xxx?

Like float(922) is 922.0, Not 9.22

> **I want to know why float(sys.maxsize) gets smaller than sys.maxsize.**

Thanks for the answers to my question, and hope you have a great day.

Comment: That is the scientific notation, see the e+18 at the end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert float to string in positional format (without scientific notation and false precision)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847690/convert-float-to-string-in-positional-format-without-scientific-notation-and-fa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That point is caused by the fact that the `__repr__` method of class `float` uses the **scientific notation**.

Do you see that `e+18` at the end? It means the number is the floated-point-number *multiplied* for `10` at the power of `18`.

---

If you don't want it to happen, simply avoid using `float`, or represent the `float` using [numpy.format_float_positional](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_positional.html).

Comment: @jeongwonbahk if it worked please accept my answer to mark it as a working one.