# Differences of float in python2 and python3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I wrote those simple lines and run them on python 2/3.

```
i=1.194857193845710948754654
print(len(str(i)))
```

I got 2 different outputs. What is the reason for that? and how could I achieve the same output in python2 ?

Output python2:

```
>>> 13
```

Output python3:

```
>>> 18
```

Comment: Take a look at [Floating Point Numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20473968/4014959)

Answer (score 3):

It's because of different implementation of `str()` for float, as can easily be verified.

The actual float precision is the same.

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.9
>>> i=1.194857193845710948754654
>>> i
1.1948571938457109
>>> str(i)
'1.19485719385'
>>>
```

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.3
>>> i=1.194857193845710948754654
>>> i
1.1948571938457109
>>> str(i)
'1.1948571938457109'
>>>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this solved my problem. I didnt thought the string conversion could be the limiting factor :)