# Decimal rounding in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand the decimal rounding behavior in python. What I find strange is the following:

1) Multiplying 70 by 11.46950 gives me 802.865

2) Multiplying 70 by 11.46750 gives me 802.7249999999999

Why is there extra precision in the second case and not the first case? I understand that internally, the decimal cannot be represented exactly. But that reason should also apply to the first case as well?

I am using python3.6.

Thanks

Comment: Try printing with more digits, eg `print(format(70 * 11.46750, '.50f'))`

Comment: Does the info here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473968/floating-point-numbers Basically, the result of `70 * 11.46950` is slightly over 802.865 and the result of `70 * 11.46950` is slightly under 802.725

Comment: Yes it did. thanks